# How to add schema on demand with pods using Kubernetes in postgres

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, yaml

I am successfully implemented basic PostgreSQL using Kubernetes. Once pods are created successfully, I went that pod and created the database manually.

I think we should not do it manually right. May I know how to automatically created the schema and database?

How to import existing databases Kubernetes YAML?

Comment: You can use ConfigMap to provide a schema when the pods are created. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/

Comment: The `ConfigMap` is a fine idea, and don't forget that [their instructions for extending the image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) say you can use shell scripts, too, not just `.sql` files, for almost limitless customization

Comment: Thanks for response